# Sequence based method for prediction of continuous B cell epitope

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, immunology

What is Sequence based method for prediction of continuous B cell epitope? What is the algorithm/procedure of this method? Can someone please explain this to me in simple language?

Comment: Why do you want to know, and do you have some background?

Comment: umm I am going through this for my research , but i have not studied biology for the last 8 years....